# Where is Android AVD Manager located on Mac?

Tags: android, macos, adt

How can I run AVD Manager on Mac? I mean **what is the exact file name which I should double-click on** to run AVD Manager? I found `android-sdk` folder but can't understand where is the executable file... At the same time it is not shown in Eclipse under `Window` menu tab.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Go to `<ANDROID_SDK>/tools` and double-click on `android`, it will open.
Then in the menu select **Tools -> Manage AVDs**.

## UPDATE

The android command is no longer available.

For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use `tools/bin/sdkmanager` and `tools/bin/avdmanager`.

Comment: But where is the Android SDK directory? I can open Android SDK Manager and the AVD Manager from within Android Studio, so they're installed, but I can't even tell where it's located on my drive. I'd like to be able to open the SDK Manager without having to open Android Studio.

Comment: The SDK directory is usually located in ~/Library/Android/sdk/

Comment: `Invalid or unsupported command ""` then it gives a bunch of arguments that I should use in terminal.

Comment: **[Follow these instructions](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/)** to get back the **Android SDK Manager GUI** with latest SDK 27 on your Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 20):

cd to `<ANDROID_SDK>/tools` in the Terminal and open the Android Virtual Device Manager by typing

```
./android avd
```

OR

```
ln -s ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android /usr/local/bin/android
android avd
```

Comment: Or use the SDK Manager GUI updated to v27 as [explained here](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/).

Answer (score 5):

You can run it using **Command Line**

```
cd ~/Library/Android/Sdk/tools && ./emulator -avd DEVICE_NAME
```

In my case:

```
cd ~/Library/Android/Sdk/tools && ./emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_26
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you find the android tool at:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
```

You can run:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd
```

**Related**

You can also do:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk
```

or

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android -h
```

I highly recommend adding the following to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/:/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.0/
```

Make sure you have these things installed before you add them to path

Comment: Thank you very much! This saved me a lot of time when running Ionic apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see Android Virtual Device Manager in Eclipse under Window menu tab, I don't think you've  installed the Android Eclipse tools correctly.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

For example, do you see Android SDK Manager?

Comment: But isn't there a way to just open the AVD without opening Eclipse?  I want to use spotlight and create a new emulator to test an APK without loading Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Window->Customize Perspective->

In the options the Android SDK and AVD will be disabled. You cannot enable them directly from this tab.

Go to the Command Groups Availablility Tab and Select Android SDK and AVD Manager.